# In AWK: Count number of ocurrences in a column in a tab separated file and write data into a new tsv file

Tags: database, sorting, unix

I have data stored in a large (20Gb) tab separated text file, as the sample below (input.txt):

```
1234 567 T 0
1267 890 Z 1
1269 908 T 1
3142 789 T 0
7896 678 Z 0
```

I would like to count the occurrences of each entry in Column 4, and write this automatically into a new tab separated file.

I would like to see the following in output.txt:

```
0  3
1  2
```

Can anybody suggest a fast way to do this with AWK?

Comment: Use perl, awk, or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{ count[$4]++ } END { for (i in count) printf "%s\t%d\n", i, count[i] }' \
    big.file.txt
```

For each value in column 4, increment the counter for that value.  At the end, print each value found and its count.  This prints the values in an indeterminate order.  If you want it in some order, either post-process the output with `sort` or sort the keys inside `awk` and print in the sorted key order.